# Refactoring: Mockito with new instance creation

Tags: unit-testing, spring-boot, mockito, refactoring

I have a class which is a client of some other application.

```
class StarFleetClient {
    private RestTemplate restTemplate = null;
    private String accessToken = null;

    public StarFleetClient(String address, String username, String password) {
        restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        accessToken = restTemplate.postForEntity(...);
    }

    public String attack() {
        return restTemplate.exchange(... )
    }
}
```

Now, I create multiple instances of this class whenever I require them. Each time the credentials would be different.

```
new StarFleetClient("address1", "user1", "pass");
```

Some other time

```
new StarFleetClient("address1", "user1", "pass");
```

and so on...

Now, this is perfectly working but the problem occurs when I'm writing the unit tests. I don't want to call actual star fleet while running tests. I need to mock `RestTemplate` but as the new instance is being created I cannot do the mocking properly.

How do I write test cases for this? Or how can I make this code testable?

Tech stack: Spring Boot, Mockito

Comment: why don't you try using `TestRestTemplate`, it is Convenient alternative of `RestTemplate` that is suitable for integration tests. They are fault tolerant, and optionally can carry Basic authentication headers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@Mock` and `@InjectMocks` annotations to achieve what you want. For the sake of simplicity I have replaced the `restTemplate.postForEntity` and `restTemplate.exchange` methods with `restTemplate.toString()` in my code excerpt.

So, given the `StarFleetClient`:

```
class StarFleetClient {
    private RestTemplate restTemplate = null;
    private String accessToken = null;

    public StarFleetClient(String address, String username, String password) {
        restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        accessToken = restTemplate.toString();
    }

    public String attack() {
        return restTemplate.toString();
    }
}
```

A Mockito test which mocks `RestTemplate` could be:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class StarFleetClientTest {

    @Mock
    RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @InjectMocks
    StarFleetClient starFleetClient = new StarFleetClient("somewhere", "user", "password");

    @Test
    public void testStarFleetAttack() {
        Mockito.when(restTemplate.toString()).thenReturn("called Mocked RestTemplate");
        assertEquals("called Mocked RestTemplate", starFleetClient.attack());
    }
}
```

Comment: This works but my use case is bit different. I'm using `restTemplate.postForEntity(...)` in the constructor itself. Once the constructor is completed mocking will work, but mocking will not work when constructor is being executed.

Comment: Testing the constructor is difficult, particularly when you do not want to pass `RestTemplate` in the constructor's arguments. I suggest to create a factory for instantiating the `StarFleetClient` or extract the line `accessToken = restTemplate.postForEntity(...);` to a new public method lets say `public void initialiaze()` and call it afterwards

Comment: I totally understand. I'm open to refactoring the code but I'm not getting how can I refactor this code. I've already created a factory, so I can test the consumer of `StarFleetClient`. But when I'm testing the class itself, I'm having trouble.

Comment: Also, I don't want to use `initialize()` method because it'll require client to call two methods instead of one, and it could prone to errors by client in case they forget to call it.

Answer (score -1):

You need to mock RestTemplate

```
 @Mock
 RestTemplate restTemplate;
```

and find a way to inject it in the class you are testing (by a setter or the constructor).
Since you are using spring, maybe restTemplate is a bean in your application and can be replaced by the mock for your test context.

And then use mockito to mock the behavior you want :

```
Mockito.when(restTemplate.get...)
            .thenReturn(something);
```

Comment: The question precisely asks the answer for the question for which you say "find a way to..."

Again, if you observe, the `@Autowired` or `@Bean` cannot be used because we're manually creating object here.

Comment: @GaneshSatpute From the answer: "inject it in the class you are testing (by a setter or the constructor)". Your issue boils down to a dependency injection question, and those are two options.

Comment: @avojak The setter is out of question because the class is not instantiated yet. The reason it cannot be passed as a constructor argument because, it violates the principle of abstraction. Making client aware of internals (and that too for just writing test cases) is not a good practice.

Comment: @GaneshSatpute I disagree that passing a dependency via the constructor is "not a good practice" - that is basic dependency injection.

Comment: I'm not saying that passing a dependency via the constructor is not a good practice. What I'm saying is, in my particular case, it violates the principle of abstraction. The client of my class should never worry about `RestTemplate`. The point behind creating the class is to abstract out these details.